# ActivityGroup start 3rd party Activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an `ActivityGroup` which has it's own interface, which should be persistent between Activities.

I have it working for my own Activities. But when I try to launch a 3rd party activity (from it's Intent{action="ACTION_HOME", category="CATEGORY_LAUNCHER"}) I get a `java.lang.SecurityException` because the `Activity` I want to start does not have the same UID as the calling `Activity`. Does anyone knows how to cirumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone knows how to cirumvent
>   this?

What you want is not possible in Android, for security reasons, as the error message indicates.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid this was going to be the answer. Thanks for your response.

Might I ask: why would this be a security threat? I still don't have special access to the Activity, do I? (Hmm maybe I have access to the onSaveInstanceState() bundle, so that I could do some bad stuff, but otherwise?)

Comment: It's more that Android does not have support for two things on the screen at the same time from multiple processes. Android wants to keep the applications in separate processes for security reasons. Hence, the `SecurityException`. It is conceivable this will change someday, but past discussions on this topic on the Android firmware groups makes it seem as though changing this will not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem.  Basically, your app needs to request permission to run the 3rd party app.

Assuming that the third party app specifies a permission in it's manifest, you need to declare a  tag in your manifest file that requests that permission.